# Выборка mysql уникальных значений по 2м полям

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с несколькими полями. id_cat и id_lay - повторяются. как выбрать все значения, но чтобы не было рядом повторяющихся. а сортировка по другому полю(это важно).  например в базе

| id_cat | id_lay |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 15 |
| 2 | 16 |
| 2 | 17 |
| 2 | 18 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 3 | 16 |
| 3 | 17 |
| 3 | 18 |

нужна выборка вроде

| id_cat | id_lay |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 15 |
| 3 | 16 |
| 2 | 17 |
| 3 | 18 |
| 2 | 16 |
| 3 | 15 |

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl` 
WHERE `lay_id` IN ( SELECT `lay_id` 
                    FROM `tbl` 
                    GROUP BY `lay_id` 
                    HAVING count(*)>1 )
```

но тут получается уникальные только для lay_id. есди добавить еще один подзапрос для cat_id то все равно не будет нужного результата. помогите.

Comment: *нужна выборка вроде* А теперь подробно по каждой записи - "выбирается, потому что ...", "не выбирается потому что ...". Пока - без сортировки.

Comment: сложно сказать. наврное выборка только уникальных значений по 2м полям устроила бы,  но нужны все записи. уникальность 2-15 и 2-16 не считается. нужно выбрать сначала уникальные 2-15 и 3-16 потом 2-17 и 3-18 например. скажем так тут запрос в ктором поля id_cat и id_lay не повторяются, пока не закончатся уникальные, а потом снова.

Comment: Вы обязаны сформулировать чёткий и однозначный критерий отбора. В первую очередь - для себя. То, что Вы сейчас наговорили - совершенно бессистемный трёп, из которого ничего извлечь не получится. Создаётся впечатление, что Вы сами не до конца понимаете задачу.

Comment: Выбираем  1ое значение из id_cat, одно (2) и для него одно значение из lay_id (15). следущая строка это следующее значение из id_cat (3) и для него следующее значние из id_lay(16). следующая строка - уникальные значения id_cat закончились поэтому берем опять 2. для него значение из id_lay (16)
как то так. теперь понятнее? 
Проще наверное так объяснить: нужно взять уникальные значения из id_cat и id_lay  по отдельности и объеденить их. (но в этом случае теряются все остальные, а они нужны)

Comment: *Выбираем 1ое значение из id_cat, одно (2)* Стоп. Термин "первое" имеет смысл только тогда, когда указана конкретная сортировка набора, обеспечивающая уникальность записей. Укажите, какое выражение сортировки следует использовать для определения первой записи. Таблица - это несортированная куча. Нет уникального ORDER BY - нет никакого первый-последний.